# 'Lodge a complaint' vs 'file a complaint'

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference between *lodge a complaint* and *file a complaint*?

I found two relevant senses for these words in the *Oxford Advanced Learner Dictionary*:

> **lodge**: to make formal statement about something to a public organisation or authority

and

> **file**: to present something so that it can be officially recorded and dealt with

So, when can I used *lodge*, and when can I use *file*? Are they really interchangeable?

Comment: Based on the rules of the site, we can't give you any answers until you edit your question to include the relevant dictionary definitions of these two words. Please only quote the specific senses you feel are relevant to the act of complaining, and tell us which dictionary you're using. (In other words: show us that you tried to figure this out for yourself, before asking strangers for help.)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133313/lodged-a-complaint-to-the-authorities-or-lodged-a-complaint-with-the-authorit

Comment: Awesome! So glad you came back and added the definitions of the words to your question! I'll add a little formatting markup to for legibility purposes. Now, after having read those definitions, do you see the difference between the words? What else would you like to know about them?

Answer (score 3):

In reference to "complaint", they are virtually identical in meaning. Usage preference is a matter of chronology and which-side-of-the-pond:

- "**File** a complaint" is more common in American English since about 1950; before that, "lodge a complaint was more common.

[Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=file+a+complaint%2Clodge+a+complaint&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfile%20a%20complaint%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clodge%20a%20complaint%3B%2Cc0) American English corpus
[image]

- "**Lodge** a complaint" has been more common in British English, but "file" has been gaining usage rapidly (in written works) since about the 1970s, and overtook "lodge" in about 2000, but lately they seem to be running neck-and-neck.

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=file%20a%20complaint%2Clodge%20a%20complaint&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfile%20a%20complaint%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clodge%20a%20complaint%3B%2Cc0) British English corpus
[image]

I can't speak for Canadians, Australians, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Mari-Lou, for embedding the ngram charts—how do you do that? On my iPhone I only know how to cut and paste the URL.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I also wonder how you did that, I haven't seen a way on my Mac (other than making a screenshot).

Comment: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/how-do-i-insert-an-actual-ngram-chart-into-my-post tricks of the trade here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them when you've gotten enough real-life exposure to English within meaningful contexts so that using them becomes natural and you won't have to  rely on charts and graphs and the question of which one is allegedly more common, few of which you'll remember when it comes time to produce a natural sentence in an  actual communicative setting.